# Parse IOS stringWithFormat only adding one set of data to NSMutableArray instead of two sets

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, nsmutablearray, stringwithformat

For my code I query parse for a `firstName` and `lastName`, I then place both of these values in strings and then i combine the strings and add a space in the middle. I then add this new string to an `NSMutableArray`. However, only the first instances is being added to the array. All other arrays as shown in the code get the correct number of data values. Here is my code.

```
   for (PFObject *object in objects) {
                NSLog(@"%@", objects[i]);
                NSString *phonenumber = object[@"phoneNumber"];
                NSString *firstname = object[@"firstName"];
                NSString *lastname = object [@"lastName"];
                NSString *email = object [@"email"];
                NSString *combinedname = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", firstname, lastname];
                NSLog(@"%@",combinedname);
                NSLog(@"%@", phonenumber);
                [phoneNUMBERS addObject:phonenumber];
                [firstNAMES addObject:firstname];
                [lastNAMES addObject:lastname];
                [EMAILS addObject:email];
                [combinedNAMES addObject:combinedname];
                  NSLog(@"y0");
                NSLog(@"%@",combinedNAMES);
            }
```

Is there any reason why `combinedNAMES` only gets the first set of first and last names and not the second?

So for example the two firstNames stored in parse are Jack and John, and their last names are Apple and Gardner. The array only stores the name Jack Apple and does not store John Gardner. However, the array containing the first names contains both Jack and John

```
-(IBAction)displayfriendinfo:(id)sender{
    phoneNUMBERS = [NSMutableArray new];
    firstNAMES =[NSMutableArray new];
    lastNAMES = [NSMutableArray new];
    EMAILS = [NSMutableArray new];
    combinedNAMES = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
// Initialize table data
    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"friendsAssociation"];
//quesrys the class Friend asssociation to find when instances of "user" equal the
//logged in user's username
     [query whereKey:@"user" equalTo:usernamecontrol];
     [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            // The find succeeded.
            NSLog(@"Successfully retrieved %d users.", objects.count);
           // Do something with the found objects
            ContactTableViewController *contacts =   [[ContactTableViewController alloc]initWithNibName:Nil bundle:Nil];
            contacts.user = usernamecontrol;
            contacts.COMBINEDNAMES = [NSMutableArray new];
            contacts.FIRSTNAMES = [NSMutableArray new];
            contacts.PHONENUMBERS = [NSMutableArray new];
        contacts.COMBINEDNAMES = combinedNAMES;
        contacts.PHONENUMBERS = phoneNUMBERS;
        contacts.FIRSTNAMES = firstNAMES;

        [self presentViewController:contacts animated:YES completion:Nil];


        if (objects.count == 0) {
            //uialert letting the user know that no phone number matches the query
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"No User"
                                                            message:@"No user matches this username"
                                                           delegate:self
                                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                  otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [alert show];








        }
        //if there is only one number matching the query

        if (objects.count >=1) {


            int i=0;

            for (PFObject *object in objects) {

                NSLog(@"%@", objects[i]);


                NSString *phonenumber = object[@"phoneNumber"];
                NSString *firstname = object[@"firstName"];
                NSString *lastname = object [@"lastName"];
                NSString *email = object [@"email"];

                NSString *combinedname = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", firstname, lastname];
                NSLog(@"%@",combinedname);




                NSLog(@"%@", phonenumber);


                [phoneNUMBERS addObject:phonenumber];
                [firstNAMES addObject:firstname];
                [lastNAMES addObject:lastname];
                [EMAILS addObject:email];
                [combinedNAMES addObject:combinedname];
                  NSLog(@"y0");
                NSLog(@"%@",combinedNAMES);
            }





            NSLog(@"y0");
            NSLog(@"%@", phoneNUMBERS);







            //if there is more than one phonenumber matching the query as
            //the user to input the friends username
            //instead


        } else {
            // Log details of the failure
            NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        }
    }}];
```

}
Here is the whole method I am using if this helps spot the problem

Comment: I can't understand "only gets the first set of first and last names and not the second" mean

Comment: So for example the two firstNames stored in parse are Jack and John, and their last names are Apple and Gardner. The array only stores the name Jack Apple and does not store John Gardner. However, the array containing the first names contains both Jack and John

Comment: Does the NSLog print out all of the combinedname?

Comment: yes the NSLog that is NSLog(@"%@",combinedname) prints out both the other with combinedNAMES does not

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the `combinedNAMES` array is initialized outside the `for` loop.
i.e.,

```
combinedNAMES = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (PFObject *object in objects) {
            NSLog(@"%@", objects[i]);
            NSString *phonenumber = object[@"phoneNumber"];
            NSString *firstname = object[@"firstName"];
            NSString *lastname = object [@"lastName"];
            NSString *email = object [@"email"];
            NSString *combinedname = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", firstname, lastname];
            NSLog(@"%@",combinedname);
            NSLog(@"%@", phonenumber);
            [phoneNUMBERS addObject:phonenumber];
            [firstNAMES addObject:firstname];
            [lastNAMES addObject:lastname];
            [EMAILS addObject:email];
            [combinedNAMES addObject:combinedname];
              NSLog(@"y0");
            NSLog(@"%@",combinedNAMES);
 }
```

Comment: I have it initialized with combinedNames = [NSMutableArray new]; and it stores one set of the data but not the other so I don't think initialization is the problem

Comment: where did you initialize,  i think you did that inside the for loop !!

Comment: i updated the question to show the whole method/code